# Postfix mail server and thousands of users?

Tags: jakarta-mail, postfix-mta, mail-server

greetings all
I have a postfix mail server that contains many domains
and each domain contains many users (each user has a mailBox)

and I want to handle that when an email comes to any mailBox of any user in all domains do some java code.

any ideas how this could be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to a solution to forward all the incoming emails to one single mailbox, using postfix with mysql db, and added a thread that runs every 5 seconds to check for new unread emails to that single one mailbox using javamail

Answer (score 2):

If the users have a 'real' system account, you can put a `.forward` into their home directory that looks like

```
 "|/path/to/your/mail/handling/program"
```

which would automatically pipe the email to your program when it's received. Otherwise you could tweak the local delivery agent to do it for you.

Comment: so what you are saying is to forward all the users emails to a single mailBox ? and if that so, how can I then differ between each email that it was for this specific user ?

Comment: No. The .forward file has multiple functions, with the syntax above, it'll pipe the mail to a program. As for differentiating, it's an email: look at the headers and see what the To: address is.

Comment: Well, you'll actually want the *envelope* rather than the `To` header.  Mailing lists, aliases, bcc, etc. will cause the recipient to not be listed by name in the RFC 822 message headers.

Comment: True enough. Either way, the program that receives the piped email will get the full email headers/body, and you can extract whatever you want from it.

Comment: thanks a lot about the explanation but can you please give me a tutorial link about how to configure and use the .forward ? coz the picture is not yet clear for me ?

Comment: and excuse me what did you meant by users having real system accounts ?

Comment: real system account is one that you can log into, e.g. it's listed in /etc/passwd, has a shell, etc... As for a picture, I don't know what else to put. the .forward is just a plain text file, and the example above (with appropriate path) is all you need.

Comment: aha got it, but what if the users doesn't have real system accounts, do you have any ideas for this case ?

Comment: Then you'd have to tell postfix to forward it directly to your app

Comment: I got to a solution to forward all the incoming emails to one single mailbox.